# do i need one controller action per view template in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, controller

I am pretty new at ROR, I am currently building an simple platform application, where users can go login to their on dashboard and sign up for services. Now I have several pages that is just for information for the users only, like welcome page, or the how_to page. I would like to restrict access these pages to be only accessed after the user signed in.

my question is, do i need a separate action in my UserController, to display link to these view templates? for example

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController


    def welcome
    end

    def howto
    end
end
```

here is my route file.

```
resources :users
resources :sessions, only: [:new,:create,:destroy]

root 'main#index'
match '/pro', to: 'main#pro', via:'get'


match '/signup',  to: 'users#new',            via: 'get'
match '/signin',  to: 'sessions#new',         via: 'get'
match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy',     via: 'delete'
```

EDIT:

Okay I think I am starting to get the picture now.. In my case, There wouldnt be conditional content for the same view template, the dashboard templates have a completely different layout and structure than my public view templates. I can restrict access to my whole controller that would require user to sign In before view. My question still persists. If I have a bunch of view templates for authorized user only, Do i need to make a new action for each of those template in my restricted controllers?

Comment: To display those pages, yes you'll need routes set up for them.

Comment: what if someone has a lot of these pages that needs be display for authorized users, like for a larger application, wouldnt this get out of hand?

Comment: You don't need to duplicate each view (1 for signed in users and the other for without) set up a current_user and login_required method in your application helper.  This way you can (in views too) conditionally display information if they are signed in.  Any case where the whole page should require a login, just add a before_filter of :login_required to that/those action(s).

Comment: you should look into the cancancan gem

Comment: Create a pages model and controller and allow an admin to input content

Comment: Okay I think I am starting to get the picture now..
In my case, There wouldnt be conditional content for the same view template, the dashboard templates have a completely different layout and structure than my public view templates. I can restrict access to my whole controller that would require user to sign In before view.

My question still persists. If I have a bunch of view templates for authorized user only, Do i need to make a new action for each of those template in my restricted controllers?

Comment: have I answered your question?

Comment: yea somewhat, I think I didnt quite understand REST and restful routes from the start.

Answer (score 0):

you could use one action for all pages, and write something like:

```
get "/:page" => "user#page", constraints: { page: /welcome|about/ }
```

and then in your controller:

```
def page
  render params[:page]
end
```